# Getting error in kafka as Unable to reconnect to Zookeeper, session 0x20000xxxxxxxx

Tags: apache-zookeeper, confluent-platform

We are running confluent kafka (https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-helm-charts) on kubernetes(1.14.6). We have log retention of 30mins and storage as 300GB. We have 4 brokers and replication factor of 3. We have approximately 65MBps of throughput. After running after around an hour we observe below error. Kafka broker has 6GB of heap.

`[2019-09-27 12:32:05,278] WARN [ReplicaFetcher replicaId=2, leaderId=3, fetcherId=0] Error when sending leader epoch request for Map(RT-15-7 -> (currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[8], leaderEpoch=6), RT-17-0 -> (currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[5], leaderEpoch=3), RT-19-6 -> (currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[7], leaderEpoch=5), RT-02-0 -> (currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[5], leaderEpoch=3), RT-27-4 -> (currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[6], leaderEpoch=4), RT-22-3 -> (currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[7], leaderEpoch=5), RT-32-5 -> (currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[7], leaderEpoch=5), RT-42-4 -> (currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[7], leaderEpoch=5), RT-27-1 -> (currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[9], leaderEpoch=7), _confluent-controlcenter-5-2-0-1-MetricsAggregateStore-repartition-2 -> (currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[11], leaderEpoch=9), RT-21-6 -> (currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[8], leaderEpoch=6), _confluent-controlcenter-5-2-0-1-metrics-trigger-measurement-rekey-3 -> (currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[11], leaderEpoch=9), RT-30-6 -> (currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[7], leaderEpoch=5), RT-06-6 -> (currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[7], leaderEpoch=5), _confluent-controlcenter-5-2-0-1-expected-group-consumption-rekey-1 -> (currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[11], leaderEpoch=9), RT-17-1 -> (currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[7], leaderEpoch=5), _confluent-metrics-10 -> (currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[11], leaderEpoch=9), RT-21-0 -> (currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[7], leaderEpoch=5), _confluent-monitoring-9 -> (currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[11], leaderEpoch=9), RT-17-9 -> (currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[9], leaderEpoch=7), RT-02-9 -> (currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[9], leaderEpoch=7), RT-20-1 -> (currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[8], leaderEpoch=6), RT-30-0 -> (currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[7], leaderEpoch=5), RT-12-0 -> (currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[8], leaderEpoch=6), RT-32-9 -> (currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[6], leaderEpoch=4), RT-02-1 -> (currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[7], leaderEpoch=5), RT-06-0 -> (currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[7], leaderEpoch=5), _confluent-monitoring-3 -> (currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[11], leaderEpoch=9), _confluent-metrics-7 -> (currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[11], leaderEpoch=9), _confluent-controlcenter-5-2-0-1-MetricsAggregateStore-changelog-0 -> (currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[11], leaderEpoch=9), RT-27-5 -> (currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[9], leaderEpoch=7), RT-17-6 -> (currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[6], leaderEpoch=4), RT-32-3 -> (currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[7], leaderEpoch=5), RT-02-6 -> (currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[6], leaderEpoch=4), _confluent-monitoring-0 -> (currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[11], leaderEpoch=9), RT-27-2 -> (currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[6], leaderEpoch=4), _confluent-controlcenter-5-2-0-1-actual-group-consumption-rekey-2 -> (currentLeaderEpoch=Optional[11], leaderEpoch=9)) (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread)
java.io.IOException: Connection to 3 was disconnected before the response was read
    at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClientUtils.sendAndReceive(NetworkClientUtils.java:100)
    at kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherBlockingSend.sendRequest(ReplicaFetcherBlockingSend.scala:107)
    at kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherThread.fetchEpochEndOffsets(ReplicaFetcherThread.scala:310)
    at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.truncateToEpochEndOffsets(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:208)
    at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.maybeTruncate(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:173)
    at kafka.server.AbstractFetcherThread.doWork(AbstractFetcherThread.scala:113)
    at kafka.utils.ShutdownableThread.run(ShutdownableThread.scala:89)`

Rest of the configuration is default. I'm not sure what is causing this zookeeper to close the socket connection. Also I can see all my pods are healthy.
Please let me know if more information needs to be added. Appreciate any pointers for debugging.

[Grafana Dashbaord depicting brokers and partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IACtO.png)
[Other useful metrics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/smWsc.png)

Comment: Besides observing those messages, are you observing other symptoms? I would image if the Kafka broker was no longer able to function properly, those messages would be printed as ERROR, and not INFO or WARN.

Comment: Thanks for your response I have updated the error message

Comment: Looks like this exception came from a node ID<>3, per error message: "Connection to 3 was disconnected..." I think it indicates that node 3 closed the established connection that the node above was reading from. I would match timestamps and dig deeper on node 3, to try to find out why it closed the connection. Hopefully you'll find a corresponding log entry there.

Comment: @Christoph we finally realized that this was due to the throughput limit of GCP VM's disk. We confirmed the same by increasing the disk size and observed we didnt had the same error any more. For some reason GCP's disk throughput increases with the size. Thanks again for your response.